# How to set struct alignment in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I need to set the struct alignment in XCode to 1-byte packing, and adding the pragma "#pragma pack(1)" doesn't seem to have any effect.
Is there another way to do this?
I have to read legacy data, so hand-packing is not an option.
Thanks,

Bill

Comment: Proper serialization/deserialization routines are always the right option over relying on compiler packing and endianness.

Comment: As it doesn't seems to be a matter of command (see my edit) could you show the piece of code concerned? Perhaps there's something more involved. Or perhaps this is somewhat a default behavior for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode is using GCC, so you must use GCC specific instructions : http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

For example :

```
  struct S { char f[3]; } __attribute__ ((aligned (1)));
```

This struct will thus be aligned with a minimum of 1 byte.

You also have the packed attribute, which specify that no padding should be added.

**EDIT**

I forget to mention but as @Stephen Chu mentionned it, MSVC style pragma are also supported by GCC : http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: Doesn't gcc also support this MSVC style pragma? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the size. BTW: I'm using version 4 of XCode, if that makes a difference, as they changed compilers between 3 and 4.

Comment: @BillFerster As far as I know, it still uses gcc, even if it now have a llvm front-end.
Stephen Chu : Wasn't sure about that, thanks for the link I edit my post.

Comment: Version 4 of XCode uses the LLVM compiler, not the GCC as it did previously, so those commands/pragmas won't work

Comment: I had not noticed the the ; needed to be shifted from after the struct def to the end. All works great now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome :) About LLVM, thank's for the info, I knew but though it was just a little front-end, as GCC 4.2 is still used behind. That's pretty bad to have an unsupported compiler, but they don't want to switch to LLVM successors because of the license (GPL v3)...

Comment: Acutally, llvm-gcc is still gcc but with llvm as code generator: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-llvm-gcc/_index.html